# how to get the running time of a query in intellij for a search query

Tags: mongodb, intellij-idea, bson

I have built a search application in intellij idea and I want to test the performance of the search query.

I am using mongo db in backend, latest community version (5.0) and there is a 250Mb .bson file through which I need to run the query.

I am using mongo terminal (mongosh).

How do I add this .bson file to local database using mongosh. ( I tried using mongorestore in mongosh before which says it is not available).

Second ,i need to change the configuration in intellij so that it connects to local mongo. how to i do this, any suggested plugins ?

Third how do I measure the total time taken in java, (is there anything similar to starttime and endtime in java).

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I got some details on how to get time in milliseconds in java:

```
long millis = Instant.now().toEpochMilli();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).